# HTML form with a C# action, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

Here is the form I'm using, it is also located on form1.aspx:

```
<form class="col s12" method="post" id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:textbox id="num1" type="text" class="validate" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<button id="generate" type="submit" name="action" onclick="generate_click">
</form>
```

Then Visual Studio has a form1.aspx.cs where some code is stored, so I stored this there too:

```
    protected bool generate_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool valid = true;

        if (num1.Text.ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

When I build the project and run, when I press the button, it will just refresh the page, what I would like to do is alert the user when they fill the text box with "1"

Comment: You can't use `MessageBox` in a web project. You can use [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you just want to show a message box, or do you want to do something that actually requires c#?

Comment: You could just use a label besides the text box and post the msg there.

Comment: An html button won't work that way.  Should be something like  <asp:Button ID="generate" type="submit" name="action" onclick="generate_click" runat="server">

Comment: @SamIam I guess this was a bad example, but in the future yes I do. This example is for when the user puts in "1" but in the future I plan on populating another text field using a .dll someone else has made so if the user puts in "1", it is then followed by some "random" integers as indicated by the .dll.

Comment: @Nate That's probably going to require making some AJAX requests to your server.  I haven't used WinForms in a long time.  It might have some functionality that does that for you.  I don't know.

Comment: @samIam Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your button simply refreshes the page is because it is doing a client side `submit`, as opposed to running the c# server side code-behind. If you want the button to run the server side code, you should add `runat="server"` to the `<button>`. Furthermore, if you take this approach, you should probably use a `<asp:Button>` instead.

However, I suspect what you really want to do with a click is show a message box. You won't be able to do that in C# since a message box would be client side and C# runs server side.

---

Simple solution: Use `<asp:Button onclientclick>`

For more info, read here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Good luck!